# SQL Sub-query pass Data

Tags: jquery, mysql, subquery

Suddenly I face this issue. I want to pass data to Subquery but it showing some error. There is my Code.

```
SELECT transaction.TrnID as NeedTopass
FROM transaction
WHERE `Creditor` = '130' AND
(SELECT meta.MetaValue FROM meta WHERE meta.Parent = NeedTopass) = '505'
```

But it's showing this error.

> Unknown column 'NeedTopass' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join is you friend:

**NOTE:** you only must quote strings. if '505' a number its not necessary

```
SELECT transaction.TrnID as NeedTopass
FROM transaction t
LEFT join meta m ON m.Parent = t.TrnID
WHERE `Creditor` = '130'
AND m.MetaValue = '505';
```

Comment: Thanks. let me try it.

Comment: Sorry not working :(
Unknown column 'transaction.TrnID' in 'field list'

Comment: change it to SELECT t.TrnID as NeedTopass    OR   SELECT t.* as NeedTopass to see all fields from transaction

Comment: It's working but not getting exact results anymore. Is if possible to pass parameter into sub-query please?

Comment: can you post some sample data of the tables an the result that you want

Comment: from which table do you want the result meta or transaction ?

Comment: I'm just asking something like this.
Selete Transaction.TrnID From Transaction where creaditor = '5'

And meta.Parent = DB_Transaction
AND  meta.MainID = Transaction.TrnID
AND meta.MetaKey = 'Reson'
AND meta.MetaValue = 'Sales'

once again

And meta.Parent = DB_Transaction
AND  meta.MainID = Transaction.TrnID
AND meta.MetaKey = 'SalesID'
AND meta.MetaValue = '803'

And finally i want to out put all transaction ID

Comment: Finally i want to get result from Transaction table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110059/discussion-between-sila-khatun-and-bernd-buffen).

Answer (score 0):

USE `` this symbol before transaction

```
SELECT `transaction`.`TrnID`,`meta`.`MetaValue`
FROM `transaction` LEFT JOIN `meta` ON(`meta`.`Parent`=`transaction`.`TrnID`)
WHERE `Creditor` = '130' AND `meta`.`MetaValue`='505'
```